# ImportError: cannot import name 'Plotting' from 'pypfopt.plotting'

Tags: python, portfolio

I have just installed the pyportfolioopt module but get an error while executing the following import

```
from pypfopt.plotting import Plotting
```

And the error is

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Plotting' from 'pypfopt.plotting'
```

I have checked the API from https://pyportfolioopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Plotting.html but fail to see any Class by the name of 'Plotting'.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

`from pypfopt import plotting`

Instead of

`from pypfopt.plotting import Plotting`

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but unfortnately the same error-"ImportError: cannot import name 'plotting' from 'pypfopt.plotting'"

Comment: I have updated the answer. plotting itself is a module so now you could check if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when installing pypfopt and resolved with the information above. Try again.